# powershell exception calling .ctor with "1" argument

Tags: powershell, itext

I'm having trouble within a PowerShell script from our network, but only on computers other than my own.  If I logon to the other computers with my network username the script will run with no problems, so this doesn't seem like it is a physical computer-based issue.

Here is the code that starts the issues:

```
## Path to the PDF form you'd like to fill in 
$change_formPrep = ls '*template*'
$change_form = ($change_formPrep.FullName)

## The PDF that will be saved with the filled-in forms.  
$output_file = ls "*template*" 

## Load the iTextSharp DLL to do all the heavy-lifting 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom('K:~~~~~\itextsharp\itextsharp.dll') | Out-Null 

## Instantiate the PdfReader object to open the PDF 
$reader = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader -ArgumentList $change_form 

## Instantiate the PdfStamper object to insert the form fields to 
$stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($reader,[System.IO.File]::Create($output_file))
```

The script is trying to load the iTextSharp .dll file to edit .pdf files but comes up with the following error:

[Powershell Exception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrHSA.png)

The first error is the kicker, as the next few errors are a result of iTextSharp not being able to function.

Other users get this error whether the iTextSharp.dll is on the network server or their local machine so I'm struggling to troubleshoot why it works for me and no one else. Does anyone have a clue as to whats causing this error?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `ls` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem`. Is it possible that you are returning more than one result but expecting one as you are using wildcards? What do you see when you return `$change_form` to the console? Do other users have a K: drive? Permissions to read the location where it is stored. Does it work if you run it as yourself from other machines?

Comment: I'm assuming that the `K:` drive is a network mapped drive. You say that this works if you run it but not others, so I'm guessing that the others do not have the same mapped drive, or do not have permissions to the file to be able to load the assembly.

Comment: Also, separate `FileStream` creation from `PdfStamper` creation: `$fs = [IO.File]::Create($output_file); $stamper = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper($reader, $fs)`

Comment: @Matt - Each folder I run the script in has only one "Template" file so this should not be an issue.  The others have access and full permissions on the K: drive.  If I run it as myself from other machines it works fine.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician - I've tried having others run the script with the assembly located both on the K: drive and place locally on their computer

Comment: Is the K drive mapped though for these other users? What about my other question .... What does `$change_form` look like for the other users.

Comment: @Matt - Everyone has the maps automapped when they start their computer and I have confirmed they are working.  Also, the results from $change_form comeback with the single template I want.

Comment: Okay, I found the solution:  I updated another computer to Powershell 4.0 and now it is working fine.  Was hoping this was a code issue so I didn't have to update all the computers but it works!  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You could try to find the faulty line(s) and rewrite them in PS3 or PS2 if you don't want to update workstations